# Images Z-index, make frame front of images

Tags: jquery, html, image, z-index, layer

HTML, CSS gurus :)

I'm making image frame over images which changes all time. Sorry for my bad English, I'll try it explain, you can see live demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/fWUKn/

What I want is silver background frame should cover the slideshow images.Now the frame is behind the Flinstones image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index only works with `position:absolute`, `position:relative` or `position:fixed.`
Add one of those to your elements will fix your z-index problem.

Greetz,

XpertEase

Comment: Wow, I never knew it before. Thanks, its working now. I wanted check it as accepted, but it says "You can accept an answer in 9 minutes". Guys question answered, check it after 9 minutes.

Comment: Good to hear it worked! Figured it out myself by running against the same problem some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to `#slider-frame`; I guess its that simple. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/fWUKn/4/).

PS: I cannot see sliderframe.png in the fiddle. Can you update it?